# Is it possible to use css to edit buttons created with shortcode in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, shortcode

I have a button on one of my pages in wordpress and I want to float it to the right because right now it is floated left.

Can I do that with css since its created using shortcode? If so, what would I edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcode is just a shortcut for outputting normal, pre-formatted HTML. You can write a CSS rule to style the element(s) but it depends on the markup the shortcode is generating:

1. Output the shortcode and view the page in a browser.
2. Inspect with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Chrome Dev Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html) (for example) or `CTRL+U`.
3. Look for `id`s or `class` names on or above the generated elements.
4. Write a CSS rule that targets the elements using info from #3. You could add this rule in the `style.css` file in your theme folder.

It's possible that your rule will be overridden by another style; shortcode providers often "sandbox" CSS with inline styling, so that a user's other styles don't interfere with their elements. The quickest solution is to add the `!important` override to your rule, e.g.:

```css
#target {
    float: right !important;
}
```

This overrides future inline styling on the element.

- [!important rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules)

Comment: I thought that would have done it myself, but for some reason adding that to my style.css doesn't change it. If I make the same change in firebug it does float it to the right but not if I add it to my style.css. Does it matter that the css for the button is coming from shortcodes.css versus styles.css???

Comment: @novicePrgrmr Maybe your CSS rule is incorrect or it's being wiped out by a "closer" styling. Check the `styles` tab in Firebug to make sure your style is there and that it's not crossed out.

Comment: @novicePrgrmr use `!important`. Updated answer.